# HTTPS Traffic - connection reset

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, iis

I am running Windows server 2022 with IIS installed, and my website is working for http://help.revonecompanies.com, but the connection is being reset whenever I try to go to https://help.revonecompanies.com.

The windows firewall is disabled, and if it matters the security group on my AWS EC2 instance allows all https traffic into it as well.

I have enabled TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, and 1.3.

The binding has the SSL cert and SSL Labs and SSL shopper have verified the certificate is good, but still no go for any traffic.

I am going to attach some wireshark packets for this, but I am not sure what is happening here.

[Wireshark 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHm4x.png)
[Wireshark 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIjt0.png)
[Wireshark 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrt5n.png)
[Wireshark 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXTC9.png)

Also, here is a curl of the domain over 443: [Curl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk7lq.png)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was as simple as I expected it to be. In your site's SSL settings, my checkbox was clicked to accept client certificates, but if you click to ignore them, the traffic flows just fine.

Comment: But an answer without analysis is less helpful. Usually people should run a detailed report to learn all related configuration, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html and then tell the possible causes from it. Like you found that, if mutual/two-way SSL/TLS is configured (accepting or requiring client certificates), then the behavior is different from one-way. Most web sites only need one-way.